# issue with Installing cylowess python package on windows

Tags: python, installation, python-wheel

I want to install python package cylowess

https://pypi.org/project/cylowess/

but getting the below error, but it is able to install on linux machine on kaggle kernals
if anyone can provide the .whl file then also it will be helpful

```
pip install cylowess
Collecting cylowess
  Using cached cylowess-1.0.0.tar.gz (54 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: cylowess
  Building wheel for cylowess (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      cylowess.c
      C:\Users\Manoj\anaconda3\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cylowess
  Running setup.py clean for cylowess
Failed to build cylowess
```